# CordovaWebView.loadUrl is timing out on a javascript: URL

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview

I have an Android application that contains several CordovaWebViews. (Note: I'm doing maintenance on an app that's largely unfamiliar to me.) The various WebViews send messages to each other using the loadUrl function in CordovaWebView, with a string of **"javascript:  ('toggleMenu();');"**.  (The toggleMenu() function is in one of my

I made some changes to the way the WebViews are laid out (added another top-level view that holds both a slide-out menu and the main view), and suddenly these loadUrl calls are timing out: I get the dread "E/CordovaWebView(2774): CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR!" line showing up in the logcat.

**How can this be happening, since the URL I'm loading is a tiny, tiny JavaScript snippet? Where should I look for the cause of this error?**  The logcat isn't terribly helpful, aside from informing me that the call was correctly send up to the Android WebView instance:

```
D/NWCPanels(2774): <9956> sendMessage - HEADER; target: main
D/NWCPanels(2774): <9956> sendMessage - script:javascript:  ('toggleMenu();');
D/UiTask(2774): <1> run - url: javascript:  ('toggleMenu();');
D/WebView(2774): loadUrlImpl: called
```

Okay, the call got all the way to Android's WebView. There's my debug statement to show that my code thinks it worked, and then it looks like it's actually hitting webkit:

```
D/CordovaLog(2774): - Debug - toggleMenu from header. result: true
D/webcore(2774):  CORE loadUrl: called
D/webkit(2774): Firewall not null
D/webkit(2774): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
```

Maybe it's thinking about loading my URL, since it's not blocked? But then , ~3 seconds later:

```
E/CordovaWebView(2774): CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR!
```

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505204/cordovawebview-timeout-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be something I didn't mention in the question at all: the in-house framework I was using didn't like the way I formatted my functions. (It does string-manipulation to figure out the name of a function, and doing "var funcName = function(){}" breaks it.)

Nothing to see here folks, move along...

Answer (score 2):

please clear webview catch using `webView.Clearcatch()` it works fine. I have tried same and it solved my problem.